# the image is not loading due to security content policy strapi

Tags: digital-ocean, strapi, digital-ocean-spaces

I am using digital ocean spaces to hold my upload files and strapi as a backend
[image]

i am getting this error i am able to upload the image on my digital ocean space so this means configration is all ok
'and there is something to do with security policy directive i have read it already https://github.com/strapi/strapi/issues/11637#issuecomment-977244572 also tried the most liked code

`my ./config/middleware.js`

```
module.exports = ({ env }) => [
  'strapi::errors',
  {
    name: 'strapi::security',
    config: {
      contentSecurityPolicy: {
        useDefaults: true,
        directives: {
          'connect-src': ["'self'", 'https:','http'],
          'img-src': [
            "'self'",
            'data:',
            'blob:',
            'dl.airtable.com',
            'https://sgp1.digitaloceanspaces.com',
          ],
          'media-src': [
            "'self'",
            'data:',
            'blob:',
            'dl.airtable.com',
            'https://sgp1.digitaloceanspaces.com',
          ],
          upgradeInsecureRequests: null,
        },
      },
    },
  },
  {
    name: "strapi::body",
    config: {
      formLimit: "256mb", // modify form body
      jsonLimit: "256mb", // modify JSON body
      textLimit: "256mb", // modify text body
      formidable: {
        maxFileSize: 200 * 1024 * 1024, // multipart data, modify here limit of uploaded file size
      },
    },
  },
  'strapi::cors',
  'strapi::poweredBy',
  'strapi::logger',
  'strapi::query',
  
  'strapi::favicon',
  'strapi::public',
];
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to pass a domain (without the protocol), so `sgp1.digitaloceanspaces.com`. Even better is to restrict to your bucket's url like `<bucket>.<zone>.digitaloceanspaces.com`